# Changing the output of a .map depending on the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

My title probably didn't make much sense but basically what I'm trying to achieve is

Each time my .map runs. I want it to spit out the regular 'star' the next iteration after that, I want it to spit out 'star-left.'

I'm creating a rating component and decided to cheat a little by using a half star and just flipping it each time it needs to be. So basically I have 'slices' of stars. But I'm unsure how to do it with .map or if it is even possible with .map

Also if you could give me a hint of how I can make it retain it's value. Like the first 'star' would be .5, then the 'star-left' would be 1 and so on.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {FaStarHalf} from "react-icons/all";
import './Rater.css'


const Rater = () => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null)
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(null)
    const [value] = useState(100)
    const [iconValue, setIconValue] = useState(5)


    return (
        <div>
            <select onChange={(e) =>
            {setIconValue(Number(e.target.value))}}>
                { Array.from(new Array(value),(value, index) =>
                    index + 1).map(value => <option
                    key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>) }
            </select>
            <h1> Select Amount of Icons </h1>

            {[... Array(iconValue)].map((icon, i) => {
                const value = i + 1

                return (
                    <label>
                        <input type='radio'
                           name='rating'
                           value={value}
                           onClick={() => setRating(value)}
                        />
                        <FaStarHalf
                            className='star'
                            color={value <= (hover || rating) ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
                            size={100}
                            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(value)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
                        />
                    </label>
                )
            })}
            {[... Array(iconValue)].map((icon, i) => {
                const value = i + 1

                return (
                    <label>
                        <input type='radio'
                            name='rating'
                            value={value}
                            onClick={() => setRating(value)}
                        />
                        <FaStarHalf
                            className='star-left'
                            color={value <= (hover || rating) ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
                            size={100}
                            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(value)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
                        />
                    </label>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )

}

export default Rater
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a single map operation that alternates between 'star' and 'star-left' classnames? Or is it a star rating system that allows for half-stars, i.e. rating 3.4 is 3 solid, and 3.5 is 3 solid and 1 half?

Comment: @DrewReese I just want it to alternate. I didn't think about using a different map operation. That might be a better idea. The reason why I want this is because it seems every time I hover over the first 'star' the first 'star-left' also gets highlighted. Like they share the same value. But I didn't think about it might be because they actually do. Would having 2 separate map operations solve that?

Comment: Isn't 2 separate map operations what you currently have? That's what is throwing me off, it doesn't make any sense to me. You map once with `className="star"`, then do a second map over the same data but with `className="star-left"`. Do you have a picture of what you're going for?

Comment: @DrewReese let me explain again because i seem to be throwing myself off as well. This is the code I currently have. I'm not sure how to achieve this but I don't care if I use 2 map operations or not. I was just showing you all the code I have. I want it to somehow iterate 'star','star-left,'star'... and so on. I'm not sure how to do that in React. I'm using the map operation because that's what is outputting the star icon. I don't care the logic I just want to get pushed in the right direction doing it.

Comment: I guess you could just check if i in your iteration is even or odd. Then, if odd => star, if even => star-left; order depending with which you want to start. You can determine this by checking i%2 === 0 (even) and i%2 === 1 (odd).  Or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double up on the initial array and map it as you are (remove the second array and mapping), but use a modulus 2 on the array index to determine even/odd and set the alternating classname accordingly. `i % 2 === 0` is an even number, `i % 2 !== 0` is an odd number.

```
className={i % 2 ? "star-left" : "star"}
```

Component

```
const Rater = () => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
  const [value] = useState(100);
  const [iconValue, setIconValue] = useState(5);

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={e => {
          setIconValue(Number(e.target.value));
        }}
      >
        {Array.from(new Array(value), (value, index) => index + 1).map(
          value => (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          )
        )}
      </select>
      <h1> Select Amount of Icons </h1>

      {[...Array(iconValue), ...Array(iconValue)].map((icon, i) => {
        const value = i + 1;

        return (
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              value={value}
              onClick={() => setRating(value)}
            />
            <FaStarHalf
              className={i % 2 ? "star-left" : "star"}
              color={value <= (hover || rating) ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
              size={100}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(value)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
            />
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

***Note:*** Since you doubled the array the actual rating value is half of what is set in state.

I don't have your stylesheet so this is a quick/rough demo

[image: Edit half-star rater]

Comment: Gosh darn it I forgot I could use ? and : in className. Ughh Thank you so much boss man I will give you the answer thing so you get some more points. ~ Any tips for the css to get them as close togther as possible? I got the radio buttons hidden. If you want I can make another post and you can answer it too. I'm terrible with CSS

Comment: @4156 I just guessed that you flipped some of them, but a potential issue is that the stars still occupy their normal icon space, so they'll overlap in places when you butt the interior sides together, and that may interfere with the hovering/mouseOver. You may need to place the FA icons in a container that overflow hides the excess *then* move the containers where you need them. And yes, that would be out-of-scope for this issue. If you open a new issue though you'll likely get more eyes on it anyway. (*share a link here anyway*)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200257/getting-the-stars-to-line-up-css is the link for the new problem. I added the CSS code as well. I think I understand what you mean from above, but I don't want to go down a rabbit hole when I can just fix it now.