# Getting the stars to line up CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a component that I use for a star rating, I decided to use FA icons to do the job by using half stars. Every works great, besides the CSS. I've successfully flipped some of the stars (FA icons only go to one side) so the stars align correctly, they just don't touch. I just need some advice on the easiest way to handle it.

Rater.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {FaStarHalf} from "react-icons/all";
import './Rater.css'


const Rater = () => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
    const [value] = useState(100);
    const [iconValue, setIconValue] = useState(5);

    return (
        <div>
            <select
                onChange={e => {
                    setIconValue(Number(e.target.value));
                }}
            >
                {Array.from(new Array(value), (value, index) => index + 1).map(
                    value => (
                        <option key={value} value={value}>
                            {value}
                        </option>
                    )
                )}
            </select>
            <h1> Select Amount of Icons </h1>

            {[...Array(iconValue), ...Array(iconValue)].map((icon, i) => {
                const value = i + 1;

                return (
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="rating"
                            value={value}
                            onClick={() => setRating(value)}
                        />
                        <FaStarHalf
                            className={i % 2 ? "star-left" : "star"}
                            color={value <= (hover || rating) ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
                            size={100}
                            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(value)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
                        />
                    </label>

                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Rater
```

Rater.css

```
input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
}

.star {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 200ms;
    /*transform: rotate(180deg);*/
}
.star-left {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 200ms;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to align stuff, is to use flexbox.

You can simply wrap your stars in a container:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
</div>
```

And then add a bit flexbox magic:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
```

You can easily adjust the margin or padding of the stars. Furthermore you can play with the `justify-content`.

Comment: I added some of the code, and nothing really changed. It was going up and down instead of side to side so I had to add inline-flex, but the stars are still pretty far apart from each other

Answer (score 1):

Create a container that is half the width of the star icon and hide the overflow. Then translate by half the width (x-axis) the left (really the right half) star.

CSS

```
input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.star-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star {
  transition: color 200ms;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.star-left {
  transform: scaleX(-1) translateX(50%);
}
```

Star Container

```
<div className="star-container">
  <FaStarHalf
    className={i % 2 ? "star star-left" : "star"}
    color={value <= (hover || rating) ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
    onMouseEnter={() => setHover(value)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
  />
</div>
```

[image]

[image: Edit half-star rater styled]